# Spark: Using mapPartition with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Lets say I am having the following dataframe:

```
var randomData = Seq(("a",8),("h",5),("f",3),("a",2),("b",8),("c",3)
val df = sc.parallelize(randomData,2).toDF()
```

and I am having this function which will be an input for the `mapPartition`:

```
def trialIterator(row:Iterator[(String,Int)]): Iterator[(String,Int)] =
    row.toArray.tail.toIterator
```

And using the map partition:

```
df.mapPartition(trialIterator)
```

I am having the following error message:

> Type mismatch, expected (Iterator[Row]) => Iterator[NotInferedR], actual: Iterator[(String,Int) => Iterator[(String,Int)]

I can understand that this is happening due to the input, output type of my function but how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get strongly typed input don't use `Dataset[Row]` (`DataFrame`) but `Dataset[T]` where `T` in this particular scenario is `(String, Int)`. Also don't convert to `Array` and don't call blindly `tail` without knowing if partition is empty:

```
def trialIterator(iter: Iterator[(String, Int)]) = iter.drop(1)

randomData
  .toDS // org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(String, Int)]
  .mapPartitions(trialIterator _)
```

or

```
randomData.toDF // org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Row] 
  .as[(String, Int)] // org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(String, Int)]
  .mapPartitions(trialIterator _)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. the function here is just to illustrate my problem. Is not the one that I want to use. Why shouldnt I use dataframes?

Comment: Because for practical applications `DataFrame` is just a `Dataset[Seq[Any]]` so you can simply consider it untyped / not type safe.

Answer (score 0):

You expecting type `Iterator[(String,Int)]` while you should expect `Iterator[Row]`

```
def trialIterator(row:Iterator[Row]): Iterator[(String,Int)] = {
    row.next()
    row //seems to do the same thing w/o all the conversions
}
```